# How to loop arrays with node.js request()

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, express

I went from passing single values into my node API to passing multiple values and the API stopped sending a response back.

Example of single values for fields:

```
tracking: "123", // Only one tracking number
carrier: "usps" // Only one carrier code
```

Example of multiple values for fields:

```
tracking: [ '9361289691090998780363', '784644233417' ],
carrier: [ 'usps', 'fedex' ]
```

I think I need to add some sort of loop but I cant figure out how to do this nor do I know what the proper terminology is to look this up. Is this related to aync? I'm lost.

```
request(options, function (error, response, body){});
```

Here is my code. Any help / additional information would be grateful in understanding what I am doing wrong.

**html.js**

```
// These are sent over in an AJAX call //
var trackingNumber = ['9361289691090998780363', '784644233417'];
var carrierCode = ['usps', 'fedex'];
```

**controller.js**

```
app.get("/api/tracking/retrieve", (req, res) => {

    var carrier = req.query.carrier;
    var tracking = req.query.tracking;

    console.log('carrier array', carrier);
    console.log('tracking array', tracking);

    var options = {
        method: "GET",
        url: 'https://api.example.com/v1/tracking',
        qs: { carrier_code: carrier, tracking_number: tracking },
        headers:
            {
                'api-key': process.env.SECRET_KEY_SE,
                'accept': 'application/json'
            }
    }

    console.log("Url: ", req.url);
    console.log("Query: ", req.query);
    // res.send("ok");

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log('BODY', body)

            var trackingData = JSON.parse(body)
            console.log('trackingData: ', trackingData);
            table = 'tracking_table';
            col = [
                'user_id',
                'tracking_number',
                'carrier_code',
            ];

            val = [
                user_id,
                trackingData.tracking_number,
                options.qs.carrier_code,
            ];

            main.create(table, col, val, function (data) {
                res.json({
                    id: data.insertId,
                    user_id: user_id,
                    tracking_number: data.tracking_number,
                    carrier_code: data.carrier_code,
                });
            })
        }
    })

})
```

Comment: Please provide more details around the API. If your API only supports a single `carrier_code` or `tracking_number`, you might need to do a queue for each combination.

Comment: I am going to contact the company and ask them.

Comment: It looks to me like you are sending a response back before making an API call, that could be an issue.

Comment: @TravisDelly I updated the code to comment out //res.send('ok);. Is this what you were referencing?

Comment: Ye, so if you need to loop network calls or sync functoins you'll want to use promise.all, you'll want to use a map which will return promises into an array and then call promise.all(arrayofpromises), and within the .then you'll send your json response, Here is more information about promise.all https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all.

Comment: @TravisDelly thank you. I will start looking into this.

Answer (score 1):

From your controller I can actually see that as soon as you get the request, you are sending the response back. How can you send response again?

I have commented your res.send('ok') and it works.

```
app.get("/api/tracking/retrieve", (req, res) => {
    var carrier = req.query.carrier;
    var tracking = req.query.tracking;
    console.log('carrier array', carrier);
    console.log('tracking array', tracking);
    var options = {
        method: "GET",
        url: 'https://api.example.com/v1/tracking',
        qs: { carrier_code: carrier, tracking_number: tracking },
        headers:
            {
                'api-key': process.env.SECRET_KEY_SE,
                'accept': 'application/json'
            }
    }
    console.log("Url: ", req.url);
    console.log("Query: ", req.query);
    // res.send("ok"); <--
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log('BODY', body)
            var trackingData = JSON.parse(body)
            console.log('trackingData: ', trackingData);
            table = 'tracking_table';
            col = [
                'user_id',
                'tracking_number',
                'carrier_code',
            ];
            val = [
                user_id,
                trackingData.tracking_number,
                options.qs.carrier_code,
            ];
            main.create(table, col, val, function (data) {
                res.json({
                    id: data.insertId,
                    user_id: user_id,
                    tracking_number: data.tracking_number,
                    carrier_code: data.carrier_code,
                });
            })
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: this fix eliminated a minor error I had on the front end, but it did not provide the response I am looking for from the API I am calling (ie: https://api.example.com/v1/tracking)